# How to Use MassTransit.IConsumer<IList> ? with prefetch count>1

Tags: c#, masstransit

In MassTransit, How to do something like this for consuming IList of events by setting prefetchCount>1?, the DataSynchronizationConsumer is consuming events published by busconrol.Publish(new DataSynchronizationMessage))

```
    public class DataSynchronizationConsumer : IConsumer<IList<DataSynchronizationMessage>>
         {
               public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IList<DataSynchronizationMessage>> context)
               {
                    return Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                       Transfer(context.Message);
                    }
                }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the batching capability of MassTransit. There is no `IList` approach for messages.

https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/batching.html